# gson parsing JSON object to map from a complex JSON file

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a problem trying to parse a json file to JSON object 
My JSON File is under the form :

```
  {  "objectJSON": [
{
 "attribute":"value",
  "attribute":"value",
  "attribute":"value",
  "attributes" :{
    "att1": "val1",
    "att2":"val2",
    "att3":"val3",
// more atts and vals may figure here ! 
  }
},
{
"attribute":"value",
  "attribute":"value",
  "attribute":"value",
  "attributes" :{
    "att1": "val1",
    "att2":"val2",
    "att3":"val3",
// more atts and vals may figure here ! 
  }
}
]
}
```

my problem is that the object "attributes" has an unknown number of arguments so I can not create a class for it , I thought about using a

```
map<String,String> attributes;
```

but I don't know how to parse it from the file especially that I want to keep my class "ObjectJSON" witch represents the root of my file.
I'm using gson of google 
thanks in advance .

Comment: Can't you use HashMap<String, Object>?

Comment: Check out: `Google Gson`, `org.json` library, Jackson library, JSR-374 Json API. Each one of those you can use freely (maybe apart from org.json one, since it's quite old and crusty, albeit also pretty lightweight in comparison).

Comment: It would be clearer if you didn't have duplicate "attribute":"value" entries. It looks like this structure corresponds to a class with a single member variable called "objectJSON" of type List<Map<String, Object>>. Or, if the "attribute" entries actually have specific known names/keys then you could create a second class to represent the entries of the list - so you could have a class with a single member variable called "objectJSON" of type List<OtherClass>, where OtherClass defines the "attribute" members and has a member called "attributes" of type Map<String, String>

Answer (score 0):

Using org.json library:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
```